# How to sort properties in PropertyGrid control of WinForms app?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid, typeconverter

**I need to sort properties** `not from A to Z.` **But** As I need it. Example Field (order=1), Active(order=2). So properties ordered as I need. So I try ExpandableObjectConverter for that.

**The original article** speaking about that https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6611/Ordering-Items-in-the-Property-Grid. Which I take following code.

**Problems I focused:**

1. When opened Form.cs in design-time first time. all is OK.
2. But second time opened Form.cs the property un-ordered. And not sorted again.
3. Re-building project doesn't affect anything.
4. I Must close Visual Studio and open it again.
5. What shall I do? Does I miss something.?

**Type Converter**

```
   public class SortedExpandableObjectConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
   {
    public override bool GetPropertiesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context) => true;

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object 
    value, Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        var PropertyDescriptorCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value, attributes);
        List<PropertyOrderPair> Properties = new List<PropertyOrderPair>();

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor PropertyDescriptor in PropertyDescriptorCollection)
        {
            var Attribute = PropertyDescriptor.Attributes[typeof(PropertyOrderAttribute)];
            if (Attribute != null)
                Properties.Add(new PropertyOrderPair(PropertyDescriptor.Name, (Attribute as PropertyOrderAttribute).Order));
            else
                Properties.Add(new PropertyOrderPair(PropertyDescriptor.Name, 0));
        }

        Properties.Sort();

        string[] SortedProperties = new string[Properties.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < Properties.Count; i++)
            SortedProperties[i] = Properties[i].Name;

        return PropertyDescriptorCollection.Sort(SortedProperties);
     }
   }
```

**Second class which used with above TypeConverter**

```
public class PropertyOrderPair : IComparable
{
    private string _name;
    private int _order;

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => _name = value;
    }

    public int Order
    {
        get => _order;
        set => _order = value;
    }

    public PropertyOrderPair(string Name, int Order)
    {
        _name = Name;
        _order = Order;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        var otherPropertyOrderPair = obj as PropertyOrderPair;

        // Sort by name if no order specified or compared property have same order
        if (otherPropertyOrderPair._order == _order)
            return string.Compare(_name, otherPropertyOrderPair._name);
        else if (otherPropertyOrderPair._order > _order)
            return -1;

        return 1;
    }
}
```

**Attribute class**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class PropertyOrderAttribute : Attribute
{
    private int _order;
    public PropertyOrderAttribute(int Order) => this._order = Order;
    public int Order
    {
        get => _order;
        set => _order = value;
    }
}
```

**Test above classes as following:** NOTE: must inside a user-control which changed inside Form.

```
public class Test
{
    [PropertyOrder(1)]
    public string ColumnID { get; set; }

    [PropertyOrder(2)]
    public string Active { get; set; }
  }
```